# date.getTime is not a functioin extJS datefield column

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

During the date filter in grid I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
    at Object.clearTime (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:6514)
    at constructor.convertDateOnly [as _convert] (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:237750)
    at constructor.getCandidateValue (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:45385)
    at constructor.= [as _filterFn] (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:45406)
    at constructor.filter (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:45222)
    at ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:45143
    at constructor.onCollectionRefresh (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:82919)
    at constructor.updateSource (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:83983)
    at constructor.setter [as setSource] (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:11193)
    at constructor.onFilterChange (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1591679946477:83515)
```

Here is my COlumn defeniation .

```
"dataIndex" : "date",
            "text" : " Date",
            "minWidth" : 120.0,
            "xtype" : "datecolumn",
            "renderer" : "renderDate",
            "filter" : {
                "type" : "date"

  }
```

here is renderDate method.

```
renderDate : function(val){
        debugger;
        val = new Date(val)
        val = Ext.Date.format(val,'d-M-Y H:i:s T'); 
        return val;
    },
```

Can anybody help me about this problema nd how to solve it. Thanks is advamce.

here is my gridstore :

```
Ext.define("MyAPp.store.base.GridStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    alias:"widget.tGridStore",
    requires: ["Ext.data.proxy.Rest"],
    model: Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
        fields: [
            { name: 'name', type: 'String' },

        ]
    }),
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort : false,
    remoteFilter: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'someURLa',
        actionMethods:{
            read:'POST'
        },  
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: "data",
            totalProperty: "TotalCount"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: ExtJS 6.5 I am using.

Comment: I could not reproduce your bug https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36hi

Comment: @pvlt ya but for me it is throwing error. The above error. I am getting error in 'ext-all-rtl-debug.js' so no idea how to make it work.

Comment: maybe the date is not always present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `renderDate` function, its function name should otherwise show up in the stack trace.

The stack trace hints to filters. The cause of the problem seems to be that you apply a filter of type `date` to the model field on the store backing the grid column. Said filter requires the backing model field to contain javascript date objects (or null), not (date-parseable) non-empty strings. At least one record loaded into the store does not contain a valid javascript date object in the `date` field.

You have to ensure that the model `fields` config defines the `date` field as type `date`, and that you provide the correct [`dateFormat`](https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html#cfg-dateFormat) so that the date strings are correctly converted to javascript date objects by the store on load:

```
fields: [{
    name: "date",
    type: "date",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:s" // whatever the format is in which you expect the date string from the backend
}]
```

If that solution attempt does not solve it for you, please post your store/model definition code and the data you load into the store.

On a side note, the `datecolumn` allows you to provide the date display format as [`format`](https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Date.html#cfg-format) config, no custom renderer required.

In short, the store/model field (`type: "date"`) `dateFormat` is needed to transform whatever date string you get from the backend, into a javascript date object; the filter (`type: "date"`) then works with a javascript date object only; and then finally the column  (`xtype: "datecolumn"`) `format` knows how to transform that javascript date object back to a human-readable format (which can be and usually is different from the format that the backend transmits to the UI).